# IFNULL and date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following select statement

```
FIRST_VALUE(date) OVER (PARTITION BY client_ID ORDER BY date ASC),0) AS first_conversion_date,
```

I'd like it to return a string or an integer if no date is available.

I tried this for example:

```
ifnull(FIRST_VALUE(date) OVER (PARTITION BY client_ID ORDER BY date ASC),0) AS first_conversion_date,
```

but got the following error:

`No matching signature for function IFNULL for argument types: DATE, INT64. Supported signature: IFNULL(ANY, ANY) at [26:9] Learn More about BigQuery SQL Functions.`

What should I do?

Comment: Perhaps the types of the two arguments must be the same? Although it says ANY, ANY, perhaps it means X, X, where X is any, but you must use the same type? Or at least a coercible type? I'm just guessing, never mind me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to avoid nulls in your result

Obviosuly you cannot mix DATE type with STRING or INT64 in same output column
So you need to CAST all into STRING as in below example

```
IFNULL(CAST(FIRST_VALUE(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY client_ID ORDER BY DATE ASC) AS STRING), 'whatever default value you have in mind') AS first_conversion_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `coalesce()`?

```
COALESCE(FIRST_VALUE(date) OVER (PARTITION BY client_ID ORDER BY date ASC),0)
```